# RecyclerView: Stop autoscrolling after notifyItemChanged(position)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an chat application in which i have used recyclerview to show messages. If new message comes then I just call `notifyItemChanged(lastMsgIndex);`which add the message in recyclerview. But it automatically scroll down to bottom.Now user has to scroll up to see previous messages.

I want to disable the auto scrolling whenever I update adapter's data.So that screen will remain at the same position.

Please let me know if need more details.

Comment: have you added transcript mode?

Comment: sorry, I am not aware of transcript mode

Comment: recyclerView.scrollToPosition(getAdapter().getItemCount()-1);

Comment: after notifyDataChanged();

Comment: Use `notifyItemInserted(position);` this will only refresh the view where item is inserted